# Accessing Simple.Data Table with Schema name throws error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, simple.data

I am using Simple.Data for Oracle version 0.18.3.1 in an Asp.Net MVC 4 application. It works fine with tables which dont precede by schema name but crashes when I try to get data from a table which MUST be preceded schema name. The error I receive is

```
"No matching table found, or insufficient permissions."
```

The query I need to execute is as follow:

```
SELECT * FROM SchemaName.TableName
```

This query works fine when I try to execute it in Oracle Sql Developer. I get results. But get above error using Simple.Data in C#. I have tried the following ways:

```
//BASE CLASS
public class BaseRepository
{
    protected dynamic DB { get; set; }
    public BaseRepository()
    {
        DB = Database.OpenNamedConnection("intranet_db");
    }
}

//Derived Class
public class EmployeeRepository : BaseRepository
{
    public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {                
        List<Employee> employees = DB.SchemaName.TableName.FindAllBy(JoinedOn:"2009-05-31");

        // I also have tried the following combinations as specified in documentations
        // DB.SchemaName["TableName"].FindAllBy(JoinedOn:"2009-05-31");
        // DB["SchemaName"].TableName.FindAllBy(JoinedOn:"2009-05-31");
        // DB["SchemaName"]["TableName"].FindAllBy(JoinedOn:"2009-05-31");

        return employees;
    }
}
```

but it keeps throwing the above mentioned error.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The following is the Stack Traces of the main exeption and its InnerException.

STACK TRACE

```
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
at Simple.Data.SimpleQuery.TryConvertToGenericCollection(ConvertBinder binder, Object& result, Type collectionType)
at Simple.Data.SimpleQuery.TryConvert(ConvertBinder binder, Object& result)
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
at MyProject.Repository.Repositories.EmployeeRepository.GetStoppedEmployees() in d:\Projects.Net\MyProject\MyProject.Repository\Repositories\EmployeeRepository.cs:line 11
at MyProject.Web.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in d:\Projects.Net\MyProject\MyProject.Web\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 17
at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.b__41()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass81.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49()
```

INNER EXCEPTION STACK TRACE

```
at Simple.Data.Ado.Schema.TableCollection.Find(String tableName, String schemaName)
at Simple.Data.Ado.Schema.TableCollection.Find(ObjectName tableName)
at Simple.Data.Ado.Schema.DatabaseSchema.FindTable(ObjectName tableName)
at Simple.Data.Ado.QueryBuilderBase.SetQueryContext(SimpleQuery query)
at Simple.Data.Oracle.OracleQueryBuilder.Build(SimpleQuery query, IEnumerable1& unhandledClauses)
at Simple.Data.Oracle.OracleCustomQueryBuilder.Build(AdoAdapter adapter, Int32 bulkIndex, SimpleQuery query, IEnumerable1& unhandledClauses)
at Simple.Data.Ado.QueryBuilder.Build(SimpleQuery query, IEnumerable1& unhandledClauses)
at Simple.Data.Ado.AdoAdapterQueryRunner.GetQueryCommandBuilders(SimpleQuery& query, IEnumerable1& unhandledClauses)
at Simple.Data.Ado.AdoAdapterQueryRunner.RunQuery(SimpleQuery query, IEnumerable1& unhandledClauses)
at Simple.Data.Ado.AdoAdapter.RunQuery(SimpleQuery query, IEnumerable1& unhandledClauses)
at Simple.Data.DatabaseRunner.RunQuery(SimpleQuery query, IEnumerable`1& unhandledClauses)
at Simple.Data.SimpleQuery.Run()
at Simple.Data.SimpleQuery.CastT
```